# How to pass parameters in jq to a function defined in the ~/.jq dotfile?

Tags: json, command-line-arguments, jq, rc, dotfiles

#### Goal

I'm trying to declare functions in my `~/.jq` so they can be re-used. I am not sure I've got the correct syntax for passing parameters. I've looked at the [builtin.jq source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq) but the recursion flew over my head. Can anyone help clarify if the way I've done it below is correct?

> ***N.B.*** I know it's more efficient to run `jq <json.txt '...'` instead of the "useless use of cat", but for clarity I've written it that way so all the jq syntax is on the RHS.

#### Source JSON (what I used as a test):

```sh
curl -s 'https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json' >json.txt
```

#### Example without using custom function

This is jq code executed on the commandline:

```
$ cat json.txt |
jq -c --arg q "colorhelper" 'paths as $p |
  select(getpath($p)?|test($q;"i")) |
  $p'

==> ["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"name"]...
```

#### Function in ~/.jq

I defined a function named `grep` in my `~/.jq`:

```
def grep($q; $f):
  paths as $p |
  select(getpath($p)?|test($q;$f)) |
  $p ;
```

...and call it like this:

```sh
$ cat json.txt | jq -c 'grep("colorhelper";"i")'
==> ["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"name"]...
```

"It works", but I'd like to know how to declare the function such that if the 2nd parameter is omitted (`"i"` in this case), it will still succeed. As-is, an error is thrown if the function is called with only a single parameter (`jq: error: grep/1 is not defined at <top-level>`)

#### Platform

- macOS 11.2.1
- `jq` 1.6 (Homebrew)

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add a suitable def for `grep/1` in ~/.jq.  For example, you could add (after `grep/2`):

```
def grep($q): grep($q; "i");
```

if you want "i" to be the default.  (You could change the default to be "" if you like, but then your query will not return any answers with json.txt.)

### Example

With ~/.jq as above:

```
jq -c --arg q "colorhelper" 'grep($q)' json.txt
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"name"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"homepage"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"readme"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"issues"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",0,"url"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",1,"url"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",2,"url"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",3,"url"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",4,"url"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",5,"url"]
["packages_cache","https://packagecontrol.io/repository.json",625,"releases",6,"url"]
```

If you also defined `grep/0` as `def grep: grep($q);` then your invocation would be a little less redundant:

```
jq -c grep --arg q colorhelper json.txt
```

### N.B.

Having ~/.jq as a file is fine but a bit antiquated: recent versions of jq have a module system which tends to assume ~/.jq is a directory.

So if your grep/1 definition was in ~/.jq/lib.jq, you would find:

```
echo '["abc"]' | jq -c 'include "lib"; grep("a")'
[0]
```

and similarly:

```
echo '["abc"]' | jq -c 'import "lib" as lib; lib::grep("a")'
[0]
```

Comment: Good info about the module system.

Comment: what's the difference between import and include ?

Comment: `include` imports a module as if it were included in place(no namespace e.g. $NAME::NAME which happens on `import`). 
The module's symbols are imported into the caller's namespace as if the module's content had been included directly.